# Data binding not working in oData BaseType

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to binding oData to my List using mock server.

My metadata.xml is

```
<edmx:Edmx
    xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
    Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="GWSAMPLE_BASIC" xml:lang="en">
            <EntityType Name="Equipment" BaseType="GWSAMPLE_BASIC.EquipmentBO">
            </EntityType>   
            <EntityContainer Name="DefaultContainer" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="EquipmentSet" EntityType="GWSAMPLE_BASIC.Equipment"/>
            </EntityContainer>
            <EntityType Name="EquipmentBO" BaseType="GWSAMPLE_BASIC.BaseEntityBO">
                <Property Name="code" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"></Property>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="BaseEntityBO" Abstract="true">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id"></PropertyRef>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String"/>
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Equipment.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

But it appear like this:

[image]

When I add `Key`:

```
<EntityType Name="Equipment" BaseType="GWSAMPLE_BASIC.EquipmentBO">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
```

It works fine:

[image]

Also, I found `createKey` will also produce an error：

> ODataModel-dbg.js:2005 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyRef' of undefined

```
this.getModel().createKey("EquipmentSet", {
    id :  "111"
});
```

So my question is, can I fix this without changing my oData metadata? Key is already defined in `BaseEntityBO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of openui5 issue [#951](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/951).

> Unfortunately datajs, the OData library we are using in SAPUI5, does not support derived entity types. As it is a rarely used feature, there currently are no plans to support this.

It seems this problem can only be solved from backend service.

Comment: Good finding! I think SAP should support this. SEGW supports BaseType configuration.